# How $x^9-1$ splits over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p\equiv -1 \pmod 9$ be a prime. Determine the factorization of $f(x)=x^9-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

*My proof:*  First of all we observe that $f(x)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x^6+x^3+1)$. The degree of the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is $\text{ord}_{(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})^*}(p)=2$. At the same way we can determine the degree of the splitting field of $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ that is $2$, hence $x^2+x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Now we have to determine the degrees of the factors of $g(x):=x^6+x^3+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$: for sure the are only factors with degree $1$ or $2$. Suppose $g(x)$ has a linear factor over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then it has also a linear factor over the splitting field of $f(x)$ that is $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. But $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}\cong \mathbb{F}[x]/(x^2+x+1):=L$ and $g(x)=-(x+1)^3+x^3+1=-3x(x+1)$ over $L$. Therefore, if $\alpha$ is a root of $g(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ then $\alpha=0, -1$, absurd. We conclude that $g(x)$ splits in three factors of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Can you check my proof, please? I have some doubts about the last part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $x^9-1$ splits into irreducible factors $x-1$, $x^2+x+1$ and another three irreducible quadratic polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p\equiv -1(9)$, which are the irreducible factors of $\Phi_9(x)=x^6+x^3+1$:
$$
x^9-1=\Phi_1(x)\Phi_3(x)\Phi_9(x)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1)(x^2+cx+1).
$$

Comment: How do you show the three factors of $\Phi_9(x)=x^6+x^3+1$ have last term $1$? Is this a property of cyclotomic polynomials?

Comment: $x^6+x^3+1=(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1)(x^2+cx+1)$ is equivalent to $c=-a-b$, $a^2+b^2+ab=3$ and $ab(a+b)=-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, which has a solution.

Comment: (+1) @user72870, Another way of seeing that the constant terms of the three quadratic factors are all $1$ is to use the norm map $N:\Bbb{F}_{p^2}\to\Bbb{F}_p, x\mapsto x\cdot x^p$. If $\alpha$ is a root of $x^9-1$, then
$$N(\alpha)=\alpha\cdot\alpha^p=\alpha^{p+1}=(\alpha^9)^k=1^k=1.$$ But $N(\alpha)$ is also the constant term of the minimal polynomial $(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^p)$ of $\alpha$, so the claim follows.